# Listen to the 'change' even of an element in the shadow DOM

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to select an element in the shadow DOM.
As I understand, there are 2 options: `/deep/` or `::shadow`

I have setup a jsfiddle to illustrate my tests:
  http://jsfiddle.net/chevdor/ph2qo5s8/4/

I am testing with and  element and I try selecting on of its div as example. I know I could use -webkit to access those but this is not what I need.

I don´t succeed on getting the elements under the shadow-root, neither using `/deep/` not using `::shadow`
I am using Chrome.

Does anyone know where the mistake could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're trying to pierce the shadow DOM of a native `<input>` tag. You cannot pierce the shadow DOM of native elements. Try using [polymer's paper-input element](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-input.html) instead. That will expose a shadow DOM you can pierce with the /deep/ or ::shadow selector.

```
<input id="native">
<paper-input id="paper"></paper-input>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#native /deep/ div'); //=> null
    document.querySelector('#paper /deep/ div'); //=> <div class="floated-label"></div>
</script>
```

Try it out yourself on Polymer's [demo page for paper-input](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-input/demo.html).

Comment: Hello williamcodes, you are totally right. I did not expect that but indeed, no way to pierce the native elements whereas it works simply fine with polymer elements. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Chevdor thanks, I'm glad you're happy with my answer. Would you mind selecting it as the correct one?